# Fail to install fxruby on Mac 10.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I use homebrew to install the fox library successfully.
When I try sudo gem install fxruby, it fails.
The error message is shown below.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fxruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking for deflate() in -lz... yes
checking for png_create_read_struct() in -lpng... yes
checking for jpeg_mem_init() in -ljpeg... no
checking for TIFFSetErrorHandler() in -ltiff... no
checking for XftInit() in -lXft... yes
checking for XShmQueryVersion() in -lXext... yes
checking for XFindContext() in -lX11... yes
checking for glXCreateContext() in -lGL... yes
checking for gluNewQuadric() in -lGLU... yes
checking for FXRbCommon.h in ./include... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling librb.c
compiling core_wrap.cpp
core_wrap.cpp:593:10: fatal error: 'FXRbCommon.h' file not found
#include "FXRbCommon.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [core_wrap.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fxruby-1.6.28 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fxruby-1.6.28/ext/fox16_c/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem (Mac 10.9.3) and followed the advice on https://github.com/larskanis/fxruby/issues/7 (actually reference a Debian installation)

This was basically to try **sudo gem install fxruby -- --with-cppflags=-I./include**

Worked for me

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well thanks,I fixed the problem. However, the Mac OS can't install old version of Ruby. I have to switch to Windows for my open source project.  ╮(╯▽╰)╭